# R apply function on symmetrical matrix

Tags: r, function, matrix, apply, symmetric

I'd like to utilise one of the `apply` set of functions to do some calculations.

First off, I have two matrices, `mat1` and `mat2`:

`mat1`:

```
    a   b   c
1   NA  NA  NA
2   1   1   1
3   1   1   NA
4   NA  1   NA
```

`mat2`:

```
       a    b    c
a    1.0   0.2  0.3
b   -0.7   1.0  0.8 
c   -0.1  -0.3  1.0
```

`mat2` is calculated using `mat1` using a function which is irrelevant here, and essentially I'd like to apply a weighting function to `mat1` which penalizes the results from `mat2` when there is less data (and therefore less accurate).

So to achieve this, I want to, for some coordinate `x,y` in `mat2`, calculate the pairwise completeness of two columns of `mat1`.

For example: `mat2["a","b"]` or `mat2["b","a"]` (should be same) would become the original values * (the complete rows of `mat1` of `a` and `b`/total rows of `mat1` of `a` and `b`).

So really the question is how can I apply a function to a matrix that loops every column for every column (double loop) and store this in a weight matrix to multiply against another matrix?

I can already compare two rows using `rollapply` from `zoo` package like so:

```
rowSums(rollapply(is.na(t(mat1)), 2, function(x) !any(x)))
```

I get:

```
[1] 2 1
```

As in, comparing a and b, 2 rows are complete and comparing b and c, 1 row is complete. So how can I compare a to b, a to c and b to c?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at your question again, and it appears that you want a matrix `X` with the same dimensions of `mat2`, where `X[i,j]` is given by the number of complete cases in `mat1[,c(i,j)]`.  Then `mat2` will be multiplied by `X`.

The number of complete cases is given by `sum(complete.cases(mat1[,c(i,j)]))`.  I want to use this in `outer` which requires a vectorized function, so this is passed through `Vectorize`:

```
outer(seq(nrow(mat2)), seq(ncol(mat2)),
       Vectorize(function(x,y) sum(complete.cases(mat1[,c(x,y)])))
)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    2    2    1
## [2,]    2    3    1
## [3,]    1    1    1
```

This is your desired symmetric matrix.